# Returning Multiple Strings with PHP Nusoap

Tags: php, arrays, string, soap, nusoap

I am trying to create a client/server that will return more than one string with Nusoap.  Below is my current code that only returns one string:

Server:

```
<?php
require_once "nusoap.php";

class zero_touch {

public function get_phone_number($ip_address) 
    {
        return "Single String";
    }
}
$server = new soap_server();
$server->configureWSDL("zero_touch", "http://aquarium.zapa.dsys.windstream.net/zero_touch/zero_touch");

$server->register("zero_touch.get_phone_number",
array("ip_address" => "xsd:string"),
array("return" => "xsd:string"),
"http://aquarium.zapa.dsys.windstream.net/zero_touch/zero_touch",
"http://aquarium.zapa.dsys.windstream.net/zero_touch/zero_touch#get_phone_number",
"rpc",
"encoded",
"Get zero_touch by ip_address");

@$server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);

?>
```

Client:

```
<?php
require_once "nusoap.php";

$client = new nusoap_client("zero_touch.wsdl", true);
$client->setCredentials("user","pass");
$error  = $client->getError();

if ($error) {
echo "<h2>Constructor error</h2><pre>" . $error . "</pre>";
}

$result = $client->call("zero_touch.get_phone_number", array("ip_address" => "10.248.17.208"));

echo $result;

?>
```

Can you guys help me out with anything that would allow me to return more than one string?  I've tried returning an array or multiple strings using other examples, and most will return an empty array or nothing at all.